# Postgresql query to retrieve conversation, last message in conversation, last message and unread count

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, structure

I have the following tables:

**users Table**

| id (uuid) |
| --- |
| someuuid |
| someuuid |

**ads Table**

| id | owner_id(fkey to users) |
| --- | --- |
| someuuid | someuuid |
| someuuid | someuuid |

**messages Table**

| id | ad | sender(fkey users) | receiver(fkey users) | content | created_at | read_at (null means unseen) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| someuuid | someuuid | someuuid | sometext | somedate | somedate |  |

Which means every message is related to an ad, and the sender or receiver is the owner of the ad.

Now i want to query for each user (In order to show in the inbox) every conversation they are member of, the content of the last message, the date that last message was created in that conversation and the amount of messages that user has not yet read in that conversation.

So to resume, every conversation between 2 users is about an ad posted by either the sender or the receiver of the message

The furthest i got is to be able to retrieve every conversation, last message in that convo and the creation date of the last message using the following query

```
SELECT *
FROM messages
    , (
        SELECT MAX(created_at) AS last_message_sent_at
        FROM messages
        WHERE (
                messages.sender = '80d1c6070a7d' -- ID to compare with (logged in users's ID)
           OR messages.receiver = '80d1c6070a7d' -- ID to compare with (logged in users's ID) 
                )
        GROUP BY ad
        ) AS conversations
WHERE created_at = conversations.last_message_sent_at
ORDER BY messages.created_at DESC LIMIT 100 OFFSET 0
```

Comment: The column name `id` implies uniqueness. Please use a different name if the column can have repeated values.

Comment: @TheImpaler it implies uniqueness of course because the ids are unique indeed

Comment: holly f guys, just because you can't answer doesnt mean you should downvote, if the question is not clear enough or there is any problem at least write a constructive criticism. this is toxicity at it's peak

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @MicheleLaFerla it is litteraly written in the question :
Now i want to query for each user (In order to show in the inbox) every conversation they are member of, the content of the last message, the date that last message was created in that conversation and the amount of messages that user has not yet read in that conversation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To provide an example of what is possible, please re-consider the details given in the question. Below is some assumed sample data that enables simulation of your problem and a potential query to solve it. However it is easy to make mistakes when we just don't know what your data actually is like, so, with many caveats, consider the example below. (nb, I used varchar(20) to avoid issues trying to simulate UUIDs):

**DDL** (so we know what we are dealing with)

```
CREATE TABLE users (
    id varchar(20) PRIMARY KEY,
    name VARCHAR(100)
);
 
CREATE TABLE ads (
    id varchar(20) PRIMARY KEY,
    owner_id varchar(20) REFERENCES users(id)
);

CREATE TABLE messages (
    id varchar(20) ,
    ad varchar(20) REFERENCES ads(id),
    sender varchar(20) REFERENCES users(id),
    receiver varchar(20) REFERENCES users(id),
    content TEXT,
    created_at TIMESTAMP,
    read_at TIMESTAMP
);
```

**sample data (assumed)**

```
INSERT INTO users (id, name) VALUES
('80d1c6070a7d', 'User1'),
('someuuid2', 'User2'),
('someuuid3', 'User3');

INSERT INTO ads (id, owner_id) VALUES
('ad1', '80d1c6070a7d'),
('ad2', 'someuuid2'),
('ad3', 'someuuid3');


INSERT INTO messages (id, ad, sender, receiver, content, created_at, read_at) VALUES
('msg1', 'ad1', '80d1c6070a7d', 'someuuid3', 'Hello', '2023-11-27 10:00:00', '2023-11-27 10:05:00'),
('msg2', 'ad1', 'someuuid2', '80d1c6070a7d', 'Hi', '2023-11-27 10:02:00', NULL),
('msg3', 'ad2', 'someuuid3', '80d1c6070a7d', 'How are you?', '2023-11-27 11:00:00', NULL),
('msg4', 'ad3', '80d1c6070a7d', 'someuuid2', 'Fine, thank you', '2023-11-27 12:00:00', NULL);
```

**Query**

```
SELECT
      u.id AS user_id
    , u.name AS user_name
    , m.ad AS ad_id
    , a.owner_id AS ad_owner_id
    , m.content AS last_message_content
    , m.created_at AS last_message_created_at
    , COUNT(CASE WHEN m.read_at IS NULL THEN 1 END) AS unread_messages_count
FROM users u
JOIN messages m ON u.id = m.sender
    OR u.id = m.receiver
JOIN ads a ON m.ad = a.id
WHERE u.id = '80d1c6070a7d' -- ID to compare with (logged in user's ID)
GROUP BY
      u.id
    , u.name
    , m.ad
    , a.owner_id
    , m.content
    , m.created_at
ORDER BY
      m.created_at DESC
```

**Result**

| user_id | user_name | ad_id | ad_owner_id | last_message_content | last_message_created_at | unread_messages_count |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 80d1c6070a7d | User1 | ad3 | someuuid3 | Fine, thank you | 2023-11-27 12:00:00 | 1 |
| 80d1c6070a7d | User1 | ad2 | someuuid2 | How are you? | 2023-11-27 11:00:00 | 1 |
| 80d1c6070a7d | User1 | ad1 | 80d1c6070a7d | Hi | 2023-11-27 10:02:00 | 1 |
| 80d1c6070a7d | User1 | ad1 | 80d1c6070a7d | Hello | 2023-11-27 10:00:00 | 0 |

**Summary of conversations**

```
WITH ranked_messages
AS (
    SELECT
          m.ad AS ad_id
        , m.content AS message_content
        , m.created_at AS message_created_at
        , COUNT(CASE WHEN m.read_at IS NULL THEN 1 END) OVER (PARTITION BY m.ad) AS unread_messages_count
        , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
            PARTITION BY m.ad ORDER BY m.created_at DESC
            ) AS rn
    FROM messages m
    WHERE (
            m.sender = '80d1c6070a7d'
            OR m.receiver = '80d1c6070a7d'
            )
    )
SELECT
      u.id AS user_id
    , u.name AS user_name
    , rm.ad_id
    , a.owner_id AS ad_owner_id
    , rm.message_content AS last_message_content
    , rm.message_created_at AS last_message_created_at
    , rm.unread_messages_count
FROM users u
JOIN ranked_messages rm ON u.id = '80d1c6070a7d'
JOIN ads a ON rm.ad_id = a.id
WHERE rm.rn = 1
ORDER BY
      m.created_at DESC
```

**Result**

| user_id | user_name | ad_id | ad_owner_id | last_message_content | last_message_created_at | unread_messages_count |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 80d1c6070a7d | User1 | ad3 | someuuid3 | Fine, thank you | 2023-11-27 12:00:00 | 1 |
| 80d1c6070a7d | User1 | ad2 | someuuid2 | How are you? | 2023-11-27 11:00:00 | 1 |
| 80d1c6070a7d | User1 | ad1 | 80d1c6070a7d | Hi | 2023-11-27 10:02:00 | 1 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/L91yOCXY)

---

Here is a PostgreSQL specific solution using `select distinct on(...)` this feature allows you to summarise rows so that only one row per the columns specified in parentheses, after "on". Then, you should (really MUST) use the `order by` clause to determine which specific row that matches the "on" columns is presented. In other words `select distinct on(...)` chooses a row with the `order by` clause determining which row (here it is the "most recent" message):

```
select distinct on (u.id, m.ad) 
      u.id AS user_id
    , u.name AS user_name
    , m.ad AS ad_id
    , a.owner_id AS ad_owner_id
    , m.content AS last_message_content
    , m.created_at AS last_message_created_at
    , COUNT(CASE WHEN m.read_at IS NULL THEN 1 END) OVER (PARTITION BY m.ad) AS unread_messages_count
FROM users u
JOIN messages m ON u.id = m.sender
    OR u.id = m.receiver
JOIN ads a ON m.ad = a.id
WHERE u.id = '80d1c6070a7d' -- ID to compare with (logged in user's ID)
ORDER BY
      u.id, m.ad, m.created_at DESC
```

**Result**

| user_id | user_name | ad_id | ad_owner_id | last_message_content | last_message_created_at | unread_messages_count |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 80d1c6070a7d | User1 | ad1 | 80d1c6070a7d | Hi | 2023-11-27 10:02:00 | 1 |
| 80d1c6070a7d | User1 | ad2 | someuuid2 | How are you? | 2023-11-27 11:00:00 | 1 |
| 80d1c6070a7d | User1 | ad3 | someuuid3 | Fine, thank you | 2023-11-27 12:00:00 | 1 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/xpoTU0CC)